# Commit "Fix #x" to default branch doesn't close the issue on Github

Tags: git, github

I guess the title explains my problem. I'm just unable to get the issue closed. Is there any settings or linking on Github I'm missing?

Comment: Directly pushing commits to master is a bad practice, this should be done in a pull request. Set the Title/description of PR to use keywords

Answer (score 0):

first of all I'd like to second Nautatava Navlakha's comment about not committing onto the default branch but instead creating feature branches and pull requests instead.

This also explains why it does not work. You commit and push directly to the default branch. But issues are closed by [merging into the default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.16/user/github/managing-your-work-on-github/closing-issues-using-keywords) instead.

When you create a pull request, you can then link this PR to its corresponding issue by using [one of the keywords documented in the Github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/linking-a-pull-request-to-an-issue).

Happy to elaborate further if this doesn't solve your problem.

Cheers,
Dominic